# Definition of stable manifold

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, manifolds, stability-in-odes

The text I am using "Nonlinear PDEs - A Dynamical Systems Approach" (Hannes Uecker) defines a stable manifold as follows

*Definition : Let $u^*$ be a fixed point of the ODE $\dot{u} = f(u)$ with solutions denoted $u(t,u_0)$ with $u(t_0) = u_0$. The set
$$W_s(u^*) := \{ u_s\in \mathbb{R}^d \ | \ \exists \beta>0, \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} ||u(t,u_s) - u^*||_{\mathbb{R}^d}e^{\beta t} =0 \}$$
is called the stable manifold*

Then this follows with the stable manifold theorem which states that a unique manifold which is tangent to the stable eigenspace exists and agrees with the above definition. However I am wondering about the following phase diagram

[image]

It appears that the stable manifold should be $\mathbb{R}^2 - (\mathbb{R}\times \{0\})$ because each point in this set is attracted to the the origin as $t\rightarrow \infty$ but only the space $W_s(u^*) = E^s = \{0\}\times\mathbb{R}$ is tangent to $E^s$.  Should the theorem state that a subset of $W_s(u^*)$ will be tangent to $E^s$ or am I missing something here? I feel like I am missing something in the definition as the the curved lines become tangent to the center eigenspace $E^c$ (which does not have a unique tangent center manifold).

Comment: From your phase diagram, what are the arrows on $(\mathbb R\times \{0\})$?

Comment: They correspond to the center eigenspace with real parts of the eigenvalues equal to zero. By continuity they have to be pointed towards the origin or are the zero vector. Honestly I don't have a description of the system, I just found this as an example of a phase diagram.

Comment: In your example, for any point not lying on $W_s(u^*)$ there is no $\beta>0$ such that $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\lVert u(t,u_s)-u^*\rVert e^{\beta t}=0$ (take, for instance, $\dot{x}=-x^3$, $\dot{y}=-y$; then the $Y$-axis is the unique stable manifold).

Comment: @user539887 That makes sense. I found another definition online that just requires $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} ||u(t,u_s) - u^*|| = 0$, but adds the further requirement that $W_s(u^*)$ must be tangent to $E^s$. I guess the issue with my phase diagram is that any convergence of trajectories must be in polynomial time which cannot be seen by the phase diagram. Thanks!